# PHP now + 60 days to MYSQL DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm struggling to get the current date/time + 60 days in PHP and to store it in MYSQL, its coming up as all 0's in the MYSQL table.

I've had to settle on doing it directly in the MYSQL insert in my PHP code by doing the following :

```
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

The problem is that I want to do an if else statement in PHP and add different number of days to the current date time.

Edited :

Here is the PHP code I was using :

> $expirydate = date("Y-m-d"); // current date
>
> $expirydate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($expirydate)) . " +60
>   days");

I then inserted $expirydate in to my `expiry_date DATETIME` field in MYSQL.

The resulting expiry_date field equals `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: `strtotime` returns integer, not string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this:

```
$date = date ( 'Y-m-d' );
$newdate = strtotime ( '+60 days' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );
```

Comment: Is the date format correct just being Y-m-d if you are storing it in a datetime field?  Does it store an empty time value?

Comment: Thankyou, I have tried this, the example above stores the datetime with an empty time, but changing it from Y-m-d to Y-m-d H:i:s  works great.

Comment: I am glad I helped, yes if you want to add the hour as well, this is the right way :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P60D'));
$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

or

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+60 days');
$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I tried these and then inserted $date in to my mysql table and it came up with "0000-00-00 00:00:00".  My mysql field is a DATETIME.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I have edited my original question to show the php code which I tried, and it gets the same wrong result of all zero's

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried in PHP?

One way is:

```
$days = 60;
$time = time() + $days * 86400;
echo date('r', $time);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, i settled on the code above but replaced the 'r' with "Y-m-d H:i:s", but I did notice it adds 60 days plus extra hour on to the current time.

Comment: The extra hour is likely because of the Daylight Saving Time transition.

Answer (score 1):

You should be more specific and show more PHP code. Anyway it's not hard to add a variable number of days in PHP to `NOW`:

```
$days = 6;
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval("P$daysD");

// Clone!!!
$dateNext = clone $now;
$dateNext->add($interval);

// Cloning is necessary if you want to use it in a loop
// because add will modify original object (thus $now)
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    $modified = clone $now;

    // Add $i days
    $modified->add(new DateInterval("P$iD"));

    // Store in database
}
```